# How to configure & package a simple Java app to use JPA

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, weblogic-10.x

I'm trying to learn JPA and I want create a simple Java command line app that will use JPA to query and update a database table.  I mapped out the the simple code needed to do this.  But I don't know how to configure the directory structure, where to place the persistence.xml file, packaging and so on.  This is just a quick and dirty learning exercise so I want to keep this as simple as possible.  Can someone spell out the steps in order to do this?

I'm using Weblogic 10.3.

Comment: You really have to pick one from "simple Java command line app" and "using Weblogic"

Comment: :) OK, my PC has the WL 10.3 libraries.  Despite that, I'm trying to keep the app as simple as possible.  

I'm new to Java/JEE/JPA so I'm a little confused about how to set up the dir structure and other configuration/packaging nuances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

persistence.xml goes in the `META-INF` directory that is at the same level as your persistence classes.  [Here's an example](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2007/06/where-to-put-persistencexml-in-web-app.html) of some valid and invalid configurations.  In the non-Java EE apps I've written, I build the JAR with persistence.xml in `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/`, because my JPA classes are in `WEB-INF/classes/`.

Comment: Does the above apply if I'm not creating a web app, rather a simple command line app?

Comment: I believe it should -- instead of your classes being in `WEB-INF/classes/`, they'll just be in `classes/`, so the `META-INF` should be a top-level directory.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand what WebLogic has to do with a Java command line app :)

Anyway, **all** the details you are looking for are available in the [Persistence Units](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html#bnbrj) section of [The Java EE 5 Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/index.html) that I'm quoting below:

> ### Persistence Units
>
> A persistence unit defines a set of
>   all entity classes that are managed by
>   `EntityManager` instances in an
>   application. This set of entity
>   classes represents the data contained
>   within a single data store.
>
> Persistence units are defined by the
>   `persistence.xml` configuration file.
>   The JAR file or directory whose
>   `META-INF` directory contains
>   `persistence.xml` is called the root
>   of the persistence unit. The scope of
>   the persistence unit is determined by
>   the persistence unit’s root.
>
> Each persistence unit must be
>   identified with a name that is unique
>   to the persistence unit’s scope.
>
> Persistent units can be packaged as
>   part of a WAR or EJB JAR file, or can
>   be packaged as a JAR file that can
>   then be included in an WAR or EAR
>   file.
>
> If you package the persistent unit as
>   a set of classes in an EJB JAR file,
>   `persistence.xml` should be put in the
>   EJB JAR’s `META-INF` directory.
>
> If you package the persistence unit as
>   a set of classes in a WAR file,
>   persistence.xml should be located in
>   the WAR file’s
>   `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF` directory.
>
> If you package the persistence unit in
>   a JAR file that will be included in a
>   WAR or EAR file, the JAR file should
>   be located:
>
> - In the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of a WAR.
> - In the top-level of an EAR file.
> - In the EAR file’s library directory.
>
> #### The `persistence.xml` File
>
> `persistence.xml` defines one or more
>   persistence units. The following is an
>   example `persistence.xml` file.
>
> ```
> <persistence>
>     <persistence-unit name="OrderManagement">
>         <description>This unit manages orders and customers.
>             It does not rely on any vendor-specific features and can
>             therefore be deployed to any persistence provider.
>         </description>
>         <jta-data-source>jdbc/MyOrderDB</jta-data-source>
>         <jar-file>MyOrderApp.jar</jar-file>
>         <class>com.widgets.Order</class>
>         <class>com.widgets.Customer</class>
>     </persistence-unit>
> </persistence>
> ```
>
> This file defines a persistence unit
>   named `OrderManagement`, which uses a
>   JTA-aware data source
>   `jdbc/MyOrderDB`. The `jar-file` and
>   `class` elements specify managed
>   persistence classes: entity classes,
>   embeddable classes, and mapped
>   superclasses. The `jar-file` element
>   specifies JAR files that are visible
>   to the packaged persistence unit that
>   contain managed persistence classes,
>   while the class element explicitly
>   names managed persistence classes.
>
> The `jta-data-source` (for JTA-aware
>   data sources) and
>   `non-jta-data-source` (non-JTA-aware
>   data sources) elements specify the
>   global JNDI name of the data source to
>   be used by the container.